# Bitcoin Insight API - How to create new address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, api, bitcoin-core-development, bitcore

I need to create new public address with private key. but there is no way to create new address using insight rest api. If you guys are aware about insight api then please share with me code snippet so, i can update my insight api library and i can create new public address using that.

Currently I have used: https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api

Comment: Anyone can help on it? It is Very urgent

Answer (score 1):

You can't "create new addresses" with the Insight API. 
The Insight API is for querying the blockchain for information.

You want to use the Bitcore Wallet Service, THAT will manage a list of addresses/wallet for you:

[Bitcore Wallet Service on Github](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-wallet-service)